# Como mostrar un array en una lista desplegable usando class

Tags: javascript, array, formularios, class

Tengo 3 cartas, donde quiero que se muestre la misma lista desplegable que toma los datos de un array.
HTML:

```
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;">
        <img src="./visa-logo-1.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Visa</h5>
          
          <select id="Formulario" class="formbank" aria-label="Default select example">
          <option selected>Banco Emisor</option>
          </select>
          <button class="botonBanco" type="button">Seleccionar</button>
        </div>
```

JS:

```
function mostrar_Bancos()
{
    TodosBancos.forEach(i => {
        document.getElementById("Formulario").innerHTML += "<option value='" +i.nombre+"'> "+i.nombre+ "</option>";
        console.log(i.nombre)});
            {   
            }

    }

mostrar_Bancos();
```

El array se llama TodosBancos.
Cuando uso el getElementsByClassName no me funciona, solo con el id

```
function mostrar_Bancos() {
    TodosBancos.forEach(i => {
        document.getElementsByClassName("formBank").innerHTML += "<option value='" +i.nombre+"'> "+i.nombre+ "</option>";
        console.log(i.nombre)
    });
    {}
}

mostrar_Bancos();
```

Comment: ¿Podrías añadir en la pregunta un ejemplo de cómo haces la consulta con el getElementByClassName? Tal vez esté ahí el error.

Comment: `function mostrar_Bancos()
{
    TodosBancos.forEach(i => {
        document.getElementsByClassName("formBank").innerHTML += "<option value='" +i.nombre+"'> "+i.nombre+ "</option>";
        console.log(i.nombre)});
            {   
            }

    }

mostrar_Bancos(); `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Efectivamente parece que el problema lo tenías ahí. En realidad hay dos problemas

Por un lado, has usado la clase **formBank** mientras que en la etiqueta has usado **formbank** (en minúsculas)

Pero el fallo principal es que *getElementByClassName** no devuelve un valor único sino un array, ya que en este caso tendrías tres *cards* con la misma clase. Deberías usar un código como este

```
function mostrar_Bancos() {
      TodosBancos.forEach( i => {
        document.getElementsByClassName("formbank")[0].innerHTML += "<option value='" +i.nombre+"'> "+i.nombre+ "</option>";
        document.getElementsByClassName("formbank")[1].innerHTML += "<option value='" +i.nombre+"'> "+i.nombre+ "</option>";
        document.getElementsByClassName("formbank")[2].innerHTML += "<option value='" +i.nombre+"'> "+i.nombre+ "</option>";
        console.log(i.nombre)});
        {                }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!